# Facebook Event Search - Access Token

Tags: facebook, events, search, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

A while ago I had written some code that searched Facebook events using the api.  I've been trying to revive that code but have been unsuccessful.  The main difficulty I see is that is that searching for public events now seems to require an access token.  The documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/) says that shouldn't be the case until July 5th but, the sample event search for me (https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=name&q=conference&type=event) returns nothing if you don't have an access_token.

So I got an access_token for my application using the facebook php sdk $facebook->getAccessToken().  The problem I am now suffering is this seems to be the wrong type of token.  It doesn't work to return any events and the query when posted into the url bar doesn't get anything, but if I switch it an access token generated by a learn graph api link the query works in the url bar (but not from my site annoyingly enough).  The type of access token I'm getting from the app is basically | and that is the type that is not working for the event search.

I am basically looking for any advice I can get.  How to get an access token that the event search will accept would be helpful. I also find it weird that I can do an event search using the url bar but, the exact same query through my app returns an empty array.  So basically anything that can shed some light on my problems would be great.

UPDATE:
I got everything working except that it still requires a user access token rather than an app access token (or none).  My other problem was caused by an oddity in the php sdk and I was able to solve it by just doing the curl queries myself.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, at this moment I'm using the access token the graph API explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) uses when my app is selected (I think it's the users's token so the app can beave as the user, and since it's my access token it's not a big deal).
But this raise another problem: I think the token gets invalidated by logging off from FB or anything similar.